# Replace odd positions in string with a random digit in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have a string from which I want to replace only the odd positions by a random digit.

For Example, the string is `'123456'`. Now the output I want is `'528496'`;
Note that the digits 1,3,5 in odd positions are replaced by random digits 5,8,9.

I know how to do this using a PHP loop but was wondering if it could be done using a regex.

I found the following two relevant solutions on the web but still wasn't able to make it work.

**Solution 1**

```
echo preg_replace('/(.)./', '$1 ', $str);
```

**Solution 2**

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/\d/', function() {
    return chr(mt_rand(97, 122));
}, $str);
```

PS: I tried to comment on these questions but since I just have reputation of 5 I was not able to :(

Comment: Try `preg_replace_callback('/.(.)/s', function($m){
  return chr(mt_rand(48, 57)) . $m[1];
}, '123456');`, see https://3v4l.org/8dDmL

Comment: you specifically asked for regex, but alternatively could use str_split, array_map, modulo if odd replace, join back together https://3v4l.org/h8U0A

Comment: No need to use `chr()`, you can use `mt_rand(0, 9)`. Starting with PHP 7.4 you can even write: `echo preg_replace_callback('/.(.)/', fn($m) => rand(0,9) . $m[1], '123456');`

Comment: My plea for the three of you to stop posting answers as comments was scrubbed before any action was taken, so I don't know if you got the ping.  Please decide whether or not you would like to transfer your comment to an answer.  Regardless, please delete your resolving comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace characters at odd index**

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/.(.|$)/', function ($matches) {
    return rand(0, 9) . $matches[1];
}, $str);
```

**Replace characters at even index**

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/(.)./', function ($matches) {
    return $matches[1] . rand(0, 9);
}, $str);
```

---

**Notes**

If your PHP version is less than 7.1, you shouldn't use `rand()` as it was a bad function which didn't work properly. Use `mt_rand(0, 9)` instead.

If you need the random numbers to be cryptographically secure, use `random_int(0, 9)` instead. This function is available in PHP 7.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfect, However what needs to be changed if instead of the odd I want to replace the even position numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the replacements without referencing the matched string at all.  Only keep the single character which must be replaced.

Code: ([PHP7.4 Demo](https://3v4l.org/SI7i4))

replace odd positions:

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/^.|.\K./',
         fn() => rand(0,9),
         '1234567'
     );
```

replace even positions:

```
echo preg_replace_callback(
         '/.\K./',
         fn() => rand(0,9),
         '1234567'
     );
```

Comment: Or since we are dealing with one byte encoded characters: `echo preg_replace_callback('~..~', fn($m) => mt_rand(0,9) . $m[0][1], $str);`